# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS in IIS 10

Tags: javascript, redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting

i want to redirect http to https using iis 10. I already tried using URL rewrite but it doesn't work, when i tried accessing the website without https:// it will return the connection is reset error, here is the web.config that i tried:

```html
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern" negate="false" pattern="OFF" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

and

```html
  <rules>
        <rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

they will return connection reset when i access it from public, if i access it within local network it will redirect to https. Is there any configuration that i wasn't aware of ? I enabled the HSTS, checked on all the checkbox, and this is my binding:
[binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yod3I.png)

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The meaning of the following rule is that if the HTTP header X-Forwarded-Proto contains "https", the rule will not perform redirection.

```
<add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
```